# Check if a template has a specialization for a given type

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Suppose we have a metafunction like this:

```
template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
struct add;
```

And we have a set of specializations for known types. For example, integral wrappers:

```
template<typename T1 , T1 VALUE1 , typename T2 , T2 VALUE2>
struct add<std::integral_constant<T1,VALUE1>,std::integral_constant<T2,VALUE2> : public std::integral_constant<std::common_type_t<T1,T2>,VALUE1+VALUE2> {}; //Take advantage of C++14 helpers
```

A few days ago, we create a new class, and we specialize addition for this class:

```
template<typename X , typename Y>
struct point_2d
{
    using x = X;
    using y = Y;
};

template<typename X1 , typename Y1 , typename X2 , typename Y2>
struct add<point_2d<X1,Y1>,ppoint_2d<X2,Y2>> : public point_2d<add<X1,X2>,add<Y1,Y2>> {};
```

As you can see, I used `add` metafuntion to perform the addition of the coordinates. So any type that has a specialization for add metafunction can be used as `point_2d` coordinates.

My question is: **Is there any way to check if a template has a specialization with a given type as argument?**

Something like this:

```
template<template<typename...> class TEMPLATE , typename... Ts>
struct has_specialization;

template<template<typename...> class TEMPLATE , typename... Ts>
struct has_specialization<TEMPLATE<Ts...> /* TEMPLATE<Ts...> exists */ , Ts...> : public std::true_type {};

template<template<typename...> class TEMPLATE , typename... Ts>
struct has_specialization<TEMPLATE<Ts...> /* TEMPLATE<Ts...> doesn't exists */ , Ts...> : public std::false_type {};
```

Comment: Do you mean to distinguish between specialization and an un-specialized instantiation, or just tell whether _some_ instantiation is possible?

Comment: You should replace every use of "specialization" with "explicit specialization". Currently as written it is extremely confusing. Any instantiation is specialized.

Comment: @Useless the last, whether a template instantation is posibble.

Comment: For an explicit specialization, no instantiation is possible by definition.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb how? Could you write an answer, please?

Comment: @Johannes Really the case im interested in is in explicit specializations, like in the example. I have forward-declared a set of metafunctions, and I write specializations for new types later.

Comment: If you're only interested in whether _some_ instantiation is possible, I don't understand the discussion of (explicit) specialization at all. Is it relevant to your question?

Comment: I think the idea of checking for explicit specializations goes against the principles of generic programming.

Comment: @Useless My use case is about forwarded templates and explicit specializations. But would be good if the checking could be done for any form of instantation, not only specializations.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz the idea is to provide user friendly compiler errors through asserts. If i can check (Following with the `point_2d` example) if the coordinates passed are addable (That is, a specialization of `add` metafuncion is or not defined for that coordinates), I can provide more readable errors like "That coordinates are not addable. point_2d needs addable coordinates for point addition", instead of the common horrible template instantation errors.

Comment: Wait for C++2014. It's going to have "concepts lite" which will allow expressing template constraints and improve template usability and error messages. As of now it is considered impossible to do what you want.

Comment: @n.m. Concepts Lite is not in C++14 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865724/will-template-constraints-be-available-for-variable-templates#comment26093535_17865724

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> @BartekBanachewicz the idea is to provide user friendly compiler errors through asserts. 
>   If i can check (Following with the point_2d example) if the coordinates passed are addable
>   (That is, a specialization of add metafuncion is or not defined for that coordinates),
>   I can provide more readable errors like "That coordinates are not addable. point_2d needs 
>   addable coordinates for point addition", instead of the common horrible template instantation errors.

Given that this is the motivation of your question would not this be an
easier and more direct solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
using cannot_add =  std::integral_constant<bool,std::is_same<LHS,LHS>::value>;

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
struct add
{
    /* Assert some expressively named condition that is always false 
        but is dependent on a template parameter.
    */
    static_assert(!cannot_add<LHS,RHS>::value,
        "Types are not addable. Need specialization");
};

template<typename T1 , T1 VALUE1 , typename T2 , T2 VALUE2>
struct add<std::integral_constant<T1,VALUE1>,std::integral_constant<T2,VALUE2>> 
: public std::integral_constant<
    typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type,
    VALUE1+VALUE2
> {};  

int main()
{
    add<std::integral_constant<int,1>,std::integral_constant<int,2>> x; // Line 25 
    add<float,float> y; // Line 26
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.8.1 diagnoses:

```
main.cpp:26:19:   required from here
main.cpp:12:2: error: static assertion failed: Types are not addable. Need specialization
```

Clang 3.3 diagnoses:

```
main.cpp:12:2: error: static_assert failed "Types are not addable. Need specialization"
    static_assert(!cannot_add<LHS,RHS>::value,
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:26:19: note: in instantiation of template class 'add<float, float>' requested here
    add<float,float> y; // Line 26
                 ^
```

Comment: Err, no, that is not as simple as you think. `point_2d` can have any type of coordinates (Normally integral wrappers like `std::integral_constant`). And your test has no sense: Why two types are addable if are not equal? Cannot add std::integral_constant<int,1> and std::integral_constant<int,0> ?

Comment: Oh, holly shit, now I understand you. Sorry about the downvote. Modify and I accept your answer. I think this is the correct way.

Comment: Only one question: The idea is when the types uses the first declaration (Wich has the assert), it means that there is no specialization for that types, right? So the assert must be false always to work, right? Why that always-false assert must be deppendent on the template?

Comment: The always-false condition of the `static_assert` needs to be dependent on a template parameter so that the compiler will not evaluate it unless it instantiates the template. Try
`static_assert(false,"etc...")` and you will see that it *always* fires. What is it that you want me to modify so you can accept the answer?

Comment: Here, have a `+1` to balance it.